# How to copy all the data from a table in Sql Server 2008 to file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a table in sql server 2008 and the table contains a lots of records.I need to get all the data from that table to a script file.

Comment: What sort of file? CSV? XML? Excel? A script to run on another server?

Comment: bcp.exe http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: Could also use SSMS's built in export wizard. If this is just a one off, it might be quicker/simpler to run a select query and then copy/paste.

Comment: @Bridge: Guess what 'script file' stands for.

Comment: @alzaimar The question was edited after I commented, to clarify OP's question. You get a 5 min window to edit without it appearing in the log (which is why it appears unedited now).

Comment: @Bridge: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SSMS;

1. Right click on your database
2. Generate scripts
3. Change radio button to *Select specific database objects*
4. Check the tables box
5. Select your table
6. Next
7. Set the filename etc
8. Click on *Advanced* button
9. Change the *Types of data to script* setting to *Schema and data*
10. Click next to finish

[Blog post here with screenshots for clarification](http://clcodesnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/sql-server-generate-database-script-sql.html)